# Can't install my script properly via setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make my script installable via pip and I wrote a setup.py file but the installation isn't working properly.

Let's assume the following scenario. I have a project called hello_world_project. Inside the project are two folders. The first folder is called hello_world_project and the second is a test folder with unittests.

Inside the hello_world_project folder are subdirectories. The structure looks like this:

- hello_world_project/folder_1
- hello_world_project/folder_2
- hello_world_project/images

folder_1 and folder_2 contain both an __init__.py file and the images folder contains simple pngs.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    (...)
    packages=find_packages("hello_world_project"),
    package_dir={"": "hello_world_project"},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'hello_world = hello_world_project.main:main'
        ]
    },
    (...)
)
```

When I install the package via **pip install .** the packages are splitted in my venv.
The lib folder for my venv hasn't a hello_world_project folder. Instead there is a folder_1, folder_2 and images folder in my venv lib folder.

I tried different approaches but when I change the setup.py to i. e. this:

```
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages

    setup(
        (...)
        packages=find_packages("hello_world_project"),
        package_dir={"hello_world_project": "hello_world_project"},
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [
                'hello_world = hello_world_project.main:main'
            ]
        },
        (...)
    )
```

I get the following error message: error: package directory 'folder_1' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed the setup py and include the folders explicit.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    (...)
    packages=["hello_world_project", "hello_world_project.folder_1", "hello_world_project.folder_2"],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'hello_world = hello_world_project.main:main'
        ]
    },
    (...)
)
```